# Upload file in PHP error - goes to PHP file without allowing me to select?

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

I understand that SO advocates that we do our research before asking, but I'm not sure how to put it another way, so I thought I'd ask directly -

I'm actually trying to do something simple - upload a file, but when I select "choose" in the file browser, it just redirects to the PHP page, which shows the corresponding error message (since nothing has been uploaded).

Would really appreciate if you can explain the process flow of uploading a file. Here's my code:

```
HTML
```

Simple form

```
<form action = "./php/upload_avatar.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <div class = "change-avatar-text">
        改变头像
    </div>      
    <!-- hidden button trick -->
    <input type = "file" name = "file" id = "change-avatar-input"/>
        <button type = "submit" class = "change-avatar" onclick = "fake_photo('change-avatar-input')"></button>
</form>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d2U4.png

The onclick is just a way to use a photo as the file button instead of a traditional button. I don't think it's relevant, so I omitted it here.

```
PHP
```

The upload file code

```
if (file_exists("../avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
```

Two things happened: when I tried clicking the upload button on the HTML page, it returned "already exists", but there's nothing in the ../avatars/ folder.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG8Vm.png

I then tried commenting out everything except for move_uploaded_file, and nothing happened.

Would appreciate your advice on this, thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
JS
```

Here's the fake photo function:

```
function fake_photo(element_id) {
    document.getElementById(element_id).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not prevent the default action of the form from happening within your onclick method. But that will not be the only problem, since you are using the submit button as the trigger to start the file chose process you will need to resubmit the form after the image has been picked.

HTML

```
<form id="myform" action="./php/upload_avatar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="change-avatar-input" onchange="onFileChanged()"/>
    <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="change-avatar" onclick="fake_photo('change-avatar-input',event)"></button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var hasChosenFile = false;
function fake_photo(element_id,event){
   //If hasChosenFile is false then we want
   //to prevent the default action of the form
   if(!hasChosenFile){
      event.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById(element_id).click();
   }
   //Else let the form submit.
}

function onFileChanged(){
   hasChosenFile = true;
   document.getElementById('myform').submit()
}
```